# How to create a sliding window over an ndarray, with wrap-around?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write some logic to return an array shifted one step to the right, with wrap around. I was relying on receiving an IndexError to implement the wrap-around, but no error is thrown!

```
def get_batches(arr, batch_size, seq_length):
    """
    Return arr data as batches of shape (batch_size, seq_length)
    """
    
    n_chars = batch_size * seq_length
    n_batches = int(np.floor(len(arr)/ n_chars))
    n_keep = n_chars * n_batches
    
    arr = arr[:n_keep].reshape(batch_size, -1)
    
    for b in range(n_batches):
        start = b * seq_length
        stop = start + seq_length
        
        x = arr[:, start:stop]
        try: 
            y = arr[:, start + 1: stop + 1]
        except IndexError:
            y = np.concatenate(x[:, 1:], arr[:, 0], axis=1)
        
        yield x, y
```

So this code works great, except when the last `y` array is yielded... I get a `(2,2)` array instead of the expected `(2,3)`. That's because an IndexError is never thrown.

```
test = np.arange(12)
batches = get_batches(test, 2, 3)

for x, y in batches:
    print('x=', x)
    print('y=', y, '\n')
```

yields

```
x=
 [[0 1 2]
 [6 7 8]]
y=           # as expected
 [[1 2 3]
 [7 8 9]] 

x=
 [[ 3  4  5]
 [ 9 10 11]]
y=           # truncated :(
 [[ 4  5]
 [10 11]]
```

Does anyone have an alternative suggestion about how to get this done? Preferably something as simple as my failed solution?

Comment: what do you expect your truncated output to be like? the array `test` ends at 11. Do you want a roll around?

Comment: @Ehsan that's exactly what I'm looking to do. It should have a final column of [0, 6].

Comment: Oh it is easier then. I will post the solution.

Comment: Do you necessarily want a generator? or array will work for you?

Comment: @Ehsan I need a generator, as I will be dealing with large amounts of data. Thanks for your solution. I'll give it a try in a little while and let you know how it goes!

Comment: `view_as_windows` uses the same shared memory (unless you store your array in a specific way. You can check to see if they share same memory easily). So it would not matter if you yield it with loops or return it. It will not use extra memory if that is the issue, and it should be way faster than generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
def get_batches2(arr, batch_size, seq_length):
    """
    Return arr data as batches of shape (batch_size, seq_length)
    """
    n_chars = batch_size * seq_length
    n_batches = int(np.floor(len(arr)/ n_chars))
    n_keep = n_chars * n_batches
    
    arr = arr[:n_keep].reshape(batch_size, -1)
    x = view_as_windows(arr, (batch_size, seq_length), seq_length)[0]
    y = view_as_windows(np.roll(arr,-1,axis=1), (batch_size, seq_length), seq_length)[0]

    return x, y
```

[`view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) uses the same shared memory (It is a view. You can check to see if they share same memory). So it would not matter if you yield it with loops or return it. It will not use extra memory if that is the issue (specially that your windows are not overlapping), and it should be way faster than generator. You probably can even achieve this by simple reshaping without `view_as_windows` too.